# Git checkout from heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I would like to "refresh" my local codebase with the code I have deployed to heroku and that is currently running.

I did a

```
git pull heroku master
```

And reveived a message saying that everything is up to date. I then tried

```
git checkout master
```

Hoping that this would overwrite my local copy of the code with what is available on Heroku. However this did not work. How do I "get" my code that is deployed to Heroku?

Comment: do a git checkout . on your branch, this will remove all your local changes, that should do. you need not have to pull the code

Comment: Oops did not post as an answer, can u accept it

Answer (score 2):

Do a `git checkout .` on your branch, this will remove all your local changes.

you need not pull the code after that

Answer (score 2):

It's just a git remote like any other. If you want your local master branch to reflect exactly what's currently in heroku (maybe your local copy diverged incorrectly), you can just

```
git fetch heroku
git reset --hard heroku/master
```